# Can't set up environment path variables in Kali Linux installation

Tags: shell, terminal, kali-linux, environment-variables

I downloaded flutter and Android studio on my linux machine. It is a kali linux installation. I want to add environment path variable for both android studio and flutter permanently so, who when I start a shell, I don't have to add them every time. I want to add to all users. I did some searching and found that you have to add the path in `/etc/profile` if you want to do for all users. But nothing seems to be working.

The original content of the file

```bsh
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
    PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
    if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
        # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
        # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
        if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
            . /etc/bash.bashrc
        fi
    else
        if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
            PS1='# '
        else
            PS1='$ '
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r $i ]; then
            . $i
        fi
    done
    unset i
fi
```

I added my paths using a `:` to separate just after else in line 4 like this

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/user1/Flutter/flutter/bin:/home/user1/android-studio/bin"
```

saved the file and restarted machine, and did

```bsh
echo $PATH
```

in the shell but the output was just this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Then I tried different method removed previous changes and added

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user1/Flutter/flutter/bin:/home/user1/android-studio/bin
```

just before export path, saved restarted the machine and it didn't work either. The `echo $PATH` command prints the same above paths.

How do I accomplish what I am trying to accomplish. I have looked at several similar questions on this site and most suggest what I have done above. Am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT**
This the contents of `.profile` in my user directory. I have only one user.

```bsh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Does your user account's shell startup files reset the `PATH` variable? What shell are you using?

Comment: @Kusalananda Hi, I did echo $0 and it said bash so I am using Bourne Again Shell. bash

Comment: @Kusalananda I have added the contents of .profile from my user directory.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux distribution geared towards various information security tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your `/etc/environment`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/user1/Flutter/flutter/bin:/home/user1/android-studio/bin
```

Explained on [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables):

> Put all global environment variables, i.e. ones affecting all users, into `/etc/environment`
>
> **Remember**, this file is read by PAM, not by a shell. **You cannot use shell expansions here**. E.g. `MAIL=$HOME/Maildir/` **will not work!**
>
> There is no shell-agnostic and login-independent solution to the problem of how to configure the environment for all users, beyond the trivial cases that PAM can handle.

You can logout then login or `source /etc/environment`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I had read about etc/environment on other answers but when didn't find the environment file in etc but found profile I thought I will have to edit profile. Also most answers had mentioned profile. I am curious. Why didn't editing the profile work?  I also tried added the path in .profile but it still didn't work.

Comment: @OpampInverting Welcome, explained here :[Using graphical display manager](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and trying to update the PATH in my ~/.profile has no effect. I also have no .bash_login or .bash_profile files. This really seems like a bug in Kali.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem just recently as well. The default shell of Kali Linux is now `zsh`. We need to place the

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/"
```

inside of `.zshrc`. Then after implementing the changes by

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

and viewing the PATH by `echo $PATH`, you will see the updated PATH. Verify by restarting the shell.

Comment: Instead of `export PATH...`, you can also write `path+=( /path/to/bin )`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Kali distribution 2021.1 works with updating `$PATH` variable in `~/.profile`.

Just add `PATH=$PATH:"/replace/with/your/path"` to `~/.profile`

Logout and login or type `source ./profile` in your home directory.

Check your environment with the `env` command.

You should see something like below

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/replace/with/your/path
```

Comment: Recent Kali Linux releases uses `zsh` as the default login shell. The `zsh` shell does not read `~/.profile`.